# How to merge CSS classes?

Tags: css

I have 3 CSS classes defined:

```
table-header-shading 
table-content-shading 
table-lines
```

Normally I would use them like so:

```
<table class="table-header-shading table-content-shading table-lines">
```

However is it possible to defined a composite Class like "ReportTable" which is comprised of these 3 classes such that I can write the following:

```
<table class="ReportTable">
```

I suspect this is a basic CSS questions, but alluding me at present.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Felix suggested something along the lines of

```
.ReportTable table-header-shading {}
.ReportTable table-content-shading  {}
.ReportTable table-lines  {}
```

To call

```
<table class="ReportTable">
```

However I am unsure whether my understanding is correct ??

EDIT2

I am sorted on this now. Thanks to all

Comment: You might be able to use a CSS preprocessor, like LESS, but CSS alone cannot do that. Or you add `ReportTable` to each of the other classes' declaration.

Comment: Thanks for this. I still would not just be able to use "Class="ReportTable" in the HTML though would I? If I can then this would be an answer as well as I only wish to call the one class. I have added an update to the above to try to illustrate your suggestion.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Thats a way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I assume you comment related to my EDIT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with "clean" `CSS`. If you will use `LESS`, you can do:

```
.ReportTable {
  .table-header-shading;
  .table-content-shading;
  .table-lines;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So is this only possible with CSS3? I have to confess I am not too knowledgeable about LESS, although I have heard of it.

Comment: Ok, now understand that I need to use LESS.js or precompile LESS to CSS. LESS looks really useful as I have a need to use variables as well.